# Graphael pie chart legend overlap

Tags: svg, graphael

I've been using [gRaphaël](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) charts for a few weeks now, and every now and then I get some weird issues. A recurring theme is that the pie chart legend labels all get squish together in the wrong places. Picture > words:

[image]

The chart is created as you would expect, in this case:

```
var r = Raphael(domNode, 300, 120);

this.chart = r.piechart(55, 55, 50, [75, 25],
    {
        colors: [
            "000-#d00-#900",
            "000-#3a3-#070"
        ],
        legend: ["Building", "Tertiary Education"],
        legendpos: "east"
    });
```

I then do some more basic styling, but turning that off doesn't help. The problem is clearly visible in the `<svg>` node (the text and circle nodes share overlapping positions), but I don't know where it comes from or why, and it only happens sometimes; other charts work just fine. There's nothing on the forums or issue tracker either, though I just realised I should probably ask there instead/as well.

Using `Raphaël 2.1.0` and `g.Raphael 0.51`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the following [blog post](http://www.shanison.com/2010/07/18/raphael-pie-chart-legend-stacked-line-problem/) which deals with this exact problem. If the pie chart is rendered in an initially hidden element, gRaphael has problems to compute the positions properly resulting in this stacked legend:

> So the solution is to render the facebox partial first, after the
>   facebox is shown, then you execute the Raphael Javascript. In other
>   word, make sure you generate the chart when the chart container is
>   there and not hidden!

I have solved this by moving the create pie chart function from the jQuery document ready directive to the on click event that will make the hidden elements visible.

Comment: I've sadly since given up on Graphael and moved back to ExtJS charts, but this looks like it was probably the problem. Hope it helps others!

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your legend as following

```
{ legend: ["Building", "Tertiary Education"] , legendpos: "east"}
```

Its the only difference taht I could find between your and [my working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/kqSEw/29/)

Comment: Copy-pasting your fiddle code has the same problem, so I assume my declaration is right. In fact when I specify a different div ID elsewhere on the page, the exact same code works fine. Presumably there's some style or bounding box problem in a few locations and the legend is getting squeezed or something, but I don't really know how that works with SVG. I'm using Dojo, so there's some non-trivial layout going on.